# Animating a button using ::after selector

Tags: html, css, button, css-selectors, css-animations

I managed to get the following button animation (see code) by using the ::after selector. However, I would like it to happen the other way around.

The initial state of my button should simply be the icon green and then the animation should take place and the button should come back to its initial state. In terms of the button colours what I am trying is:

**1st before click:** green button without pink background

**2nd after click:** animation takes place, the button turns purple and pink background shows

**3rd right after click:** green button without pink background again

At the moment what is happening is the opposite. I was wondering if you guys could tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should do to obtain the effect I am aiming for.

```
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  transition: all .2s;
  color: purple;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

  > i {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  &::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .4s;
  }

  &:active,
  &:focus { 
    color: green;

    &::after {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map"></i></a>
</div>
```

P.S.: I am using SCSS as the CSS preprocessor.

In case you find it easier, here's my **CodePen**: https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/xxxpjLa?editors=1100

Comment: simply switch the styles. you take the color inside the focus and you change it with the one in the normal state and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on an element, gives it the focus. If you click it again, it keeps giving the focus to the element, therefore it's appearance won't change unless you click on something outside of the element. If you can, I would use vanilla javascript or jquery to toggle a class that has those visual changes. The example below adds the class `green` which adds the visual changes.

With Vanilla JS:

```
    var icon = document.querySelector(".icon");

    icon.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
      icon.classList.toggle("green");
    });
```

With jQuery:

```
    $('.icon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('green');
    })
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/bjorniobennett/pen/dyyJjyW

Comment: would you mind explaining why you user &.green? This is the first time I see this.

Comment: @Fergo Sure! If you had ten buttons on a page, and you wanted all to be orange except one, you would add a class to the one you want to be green. Your SCSS would then look like this:

CSS:
    button {
        background-color: orange;
    }
    button.green {
        background-color: green
    }
and in scss/sass, could be written as:
SCSS:
    button {
        background-color: orange;
        
        &.green {
        background-color: green
    }
This link has a great explanation: https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/